# How to load APR Connector (Native) in JBoss 7

Tags: jboss, comet, jboss7.x, atmosphere

I want to use Atmosphere XMPP but i need to load native connector APR. I am not very familiar as of yet with JBoss 7 so i was wondering if anyone knows how to do this? WIndows x64 or Linux x64 environment. Doesn't matter. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming Linux x64 here. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 x64.

1. Download JBoss7 distribution and unzip it to a suitable directory ( from here I am assuming that you have it in your '/home/myname/tools/jboss701/' folder.
2. Start it using /jboss701/bin/standalone.sh and verify that it started properly ( check localhost:8080 url). Close the jboss for now.
3. Download the native libraries from here http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-9.html . I have downloaded this one jboss-native-2.0.9-linux2-x64-ssl.tar.gz
4. Unpack it to the '/home/myname/tools/jboss701/' folder. You should see the contents of the archive in  '/home/myname/tools/jboss701/bin' folder. Also, verify that you have 'native' folder under the '/home/myname/tools/jboss701/bin'
5. IMPORTANT: unfortunately, it doesn't work out of the box. You must make the following change: add the

> JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS
>   -Djava.library.path=/home/myname/tools/jboss701/bin/native:$PATH"

string to your 'standalone.conf' file.

Start JBoss with the 'standalone.sh' script. Verify that you have the following line in the console during the JBoss startup: 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol'. If you see 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol' instead of 'org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol' then everything is working as expected.

Comment: Can you specify, which WAR file are you trying to deploy? I want to try deploying it in my JBoss.

Comment: I got it working on jboss 5.1.0 with your instructions. The process was similar :) but when I configured jboss for HTTPS, the APR connector started throwing error 12:40:25,751 ERROR [Http11AprProtocol] Error initializing endpoint
java.lang.Exception: No Certificate file specified or invalid file format
 at org.apache.tomcat.jni.SSLContext.setCertificate(Native Method)
Does one need to specify certificate for APR connector as well? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks man, i got it working. I do see these lines now in my startup script.  `15:13:09,687 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener] (MSC service thread 1-7) An older version 1.1.20 of the Apache Tomcat Native li
brary is installed, while Tomcat recommends version greater then 1.1.21

15:13:11,110 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-3) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http--127.0.0.1-8080`   Atmosphere unforunately, is still throwing the same error.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and 
there is no context.xml under WEB-INF
    org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport.<clinit>(JBossWebCometSupport.java:66)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultCometSupportResolver.newCometSupport(DefaultCometSupportResolver.java:178)
    org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultCometSupportResolver.resolveWebSocket(DefaultCometSupportResolver.java:223)
    org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultCometSupportResolver.resolve(DefaultCometSupportResolver.java:217)
    org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.autoDetectContainer(AtmosphereServlet.java:900)
    org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.init(AtmosphereServlet.java:530)
    org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70)
    org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765)
    org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)`

I've set everything up as in the demos. too

Comment: Please check 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9239920/jboss-as7-apr-native-connectors-and-sendfile?rq=1