# JBoss 7.1.1 and JBoss Web Native

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, apr

I'm trying to enable the [JBoss Web Native libraries](http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/native) in JBoss 7.1.1. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342926/how-to-load-apr-connector-native-in-jboss-7) question and the answers and have tried the following steps to enable the native libraries in JBoss, but it didn't work so far. I'm on OS X:

- Downloaded the *macosx* archive from http://www.jboss.org/jbossweb/downloads/jboss-native-2-0-10
- Unzipped it into the JBoss directory, so the contents of the archive are available in `bin/native`.
- Updated `bin/standalone.conf` to include the library path: `JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=/path/to/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final-native/bin/native:$PATH"`

Starting JBoss, I can still see the following in the log file:

```
[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
```

instead of the expected `Http11AprProtocol`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Turns out the above steps are no longer necessary for JBoss 7.1.1, as the native libraries are now bundled under `modules/org/jboss/as/web/main/lib`.

To enable their usage, I had to set the *native* attribute to *true* in the *web* subsystem in `standalone.xml`. For some reason it was set to *false* in the default configuration:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" 
        native="true">
    <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
    <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
        <alias name="localhost"/>
        <alias name="example.com"/>
    </virtual-server>
</subsystem>
```

Answer (score 2):

**JBOSS EAP 6.0**

Check if you have modules/org/jboss/as/web/main/lib in JBOSS_HOME.
If not as it is in my version of JBoss EAP 6.0.

first: `yum install tomcat-native.x86_64`

Now your system has got tomcat native library under /usr/lib64 that is generally in the java.library.path
then set native=true in subsystem web as nwinkler's suggested:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" 
    native="true">
<connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
<virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
    <alias name="localhost"/>
    <alias name="example.com"/>
</virtual-server>
```

and now restart JBOSS.

Without tomcat native libraries installed you have in log:

```
10:12:31,700 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener] (MSC service thread 1-1) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk1.6.0_37/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
10:12:32,203 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-8) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/127.0.0.1:8080
```

With tomcat native libraries installed your log writes:

```
10:22:56,147 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol] (MSC service thread 1-5) Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-/127.0.0.1:8080
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

1) Download native library from JBoss web sites:

```
wget http://downloads.jboss.org/jbossnative/2.0.10.GA/jboss-native-2.0.10-linux2-x64-ssl.tar.gz
```

2) untar

```
tar xvzf jboss-native-2.0.10-linux2-x64-ssl.tar.gz
```

3) Create a folder for your native-libraries:

```
 mkdir -p tomcat-native
```

4) Move bin/native in your new folder

```
 mv bin/native tomcat-native
```

5) Make your folder visible by java. Add this in standalone.conf or domain.conf

```
 JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.library.path=[the tomcat-native's folder path]
```

Comment: Hi nwinkler. Sorry for the mistake, but the question is tagged with jboss and this is one of the first of landing pages from google search with keywords like JBoss and Native. I'm trying to change question/answer.

Comment: @nwinkler I think the JBoss EAP answer is at home here. EAP 6.0 is but a minor variation on JBoss AS 7.1.1.