# PrimePush under Jboss 7.1.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, push, primepush

I am developing a counter example application with PrimePush technology. I'm using Promefaces 5.0 and Atmosphere 2.1.6 under Jboss 7.1.1

I discovered that with Primefaces 3.4.2 and atmosphere 1.0.8 Push works. But i must use primefaces 5.0

So I'm using official Primefaces counter example

```
@ManagedBean
@ApplicationScoped
public class GlobalCounterView implements Serializable{

    private volatile int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }

    public void increment() {
        count++;

        EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
        eventBus.publish("/counter", String.valueOf(count));
    }
}
```

Here's my web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useWebSocket</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.sessionSupport</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.useNative</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.HeaderBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcastFilterClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.client.TrackMessageSizeFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.resumeOnBroadcast</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then I've configured Jboss to use the Advanced IO

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="true">
```

But when I deploy the application and click on count button I get these errors

```
10:31:50,019 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (MSC service thread 1-8) Installed     AtmosphereInterceptor @PushEndpoint Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
10:31:50,031 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS018210: Registering web context:      /pushcomment
10:31:51,515 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (Thread-71) Latest version of Atmosphere's JavaScript Client 2.2.2
10:33:03,976 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-2) Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
10:33:05,594 ERROR [org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HttpEvent is null, JBoss APR Not Properly installed
10:33:05,595 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport, error: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and You must use the  atmosphere- native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support
there is no context.xml under WEB-INF Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
10:33:05,598 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) If   you have more than one Connector enabled, make sure they both use the same protocol, e.g NIO/APR or   HTTP for all. If not, org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport will be used and cannot be   changed.
10:33:05,601 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Using org.atmosphere.container.BlockingIOCometSupport
10:33:05,603 ERROR [org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Invalid request state. Websocket protocol not supported
```

Can I use PrimePush with this configuration?
If I can't, is there another way to push data to a web page in jboss 7.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

I got this running with following versions and configuration:

Primefaces 5.0, JBoss 7.1, Atmosphere 2.1.3

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.broadcasterCacheClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.atmosphere.cache.UUIDBroadcasterCache</param-value>
    </init-param>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PrimePushServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Logfile states

```
08:57:36,055 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Atmosphere Framework 2.1.3 started.
08:57:36,055 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) 
For Atmosphere Framework Commercial Support, visit 
http://www.async-io.org/ or send an email to support@async-io.org
08:57:36,056 INFO  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Installed AtmosphereInterceptor @PushEndpoint Interceptor with priority AFTER_DEFAULT 
08:57:36,057 ERROR [org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) HttpEvent is null, JBoss APR Not Properly installed
08:57:36,057 WARN  [org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework] (http--0.0.0.0-8080-2) Failed using comet support: org.atmosphere.container.JBossWebCometSupport, error: JBoss failed to detect this is a Comet application because the APR Connector is not enabled. 
Make sure atmosphere-compat-jboss.jar is not under your WEB-INF/lib and You must use the atmosphere-native-runtime dependency in order to use native Comet Support there is no context.xml under WEB-INF Is the NIO or APR Connector enabled?
```

But it works... If someone does manage to get rid of these messages I would be happy to know how :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that your JBoss started with usage native libraries? For verification in logs try to find string `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol` instead of `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol`. If it is not true that see how to fix JBoss configuration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227993/jboss-7-1-1-and-jboss-web-native).

Also you need to use `atmosphere-runtime-native` library instead of pure `atmosphere-runtime`.

Hope it will help you.