# How to use native libraries (apr) with JBoss 7.0.2

Tags: java, jboss7.x

I try enabling APR support on jbossas 7.0.2. I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS x64 with java-6-openjdk.
For this purpose I do exactly what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7342926/how-to-load-apr-connector-native-in-jboss-7)
But after that I still have this lines in my console :

```
17:39:15,193 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener]
(MSC service thread 1-5) The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows
optimal performance in production environments was not found on the
java.library.path:
/opt/jboss/jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final/bin/native:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/share/hck:/opt/jboss/jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin  

17:39:15,319 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC
service thread 1-5) Démarrage de Coyote HTTP/1.1 sur
http--0.0.0.0-8080
```

I get stuck with this problem. Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: I had encountered similar problem some time ago and I had to recompile ARP connector from sources. But it could be something different...

Answer (score 0):

A solution, surely not the best, is describe on point 4 [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/UsingNativeLibrariesaprWithJBoss702)

For a linux x86 server :

```
mkdir -p $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/bin/META-INF/lib/linux2  
cd $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/bin/META-INF/lib/linux2  
ln -s $JBOSS_HOME/bin/native x86
```